# ImportError: No module named 'plotly'

Tags: pip, plotly, importerror

Er, this is odd.  `pip3 install` command has not left me this much clueless before.

Figure below shows the error `No module named plotly` I receive after I installed, upgraded the package `plotly` and then re-opened the terminal.

Just so that you may see for yourselves:
[image]

Searching on google did not give me much lead.. any ideas? Look forward to hearing from experts :( Thaanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to install the plotly package from Anaconda.
First you can verify if it's installed:
OSX-Terminal> conda list | grep plotly

If it does, there might be another problem.

If not, on OSX terminal run:

`\> conda install plotly`

Using pip from the standard command line when you have Anaconda is discouraged and can mess up your Anaconda installation.

Comment: Hm. yeah. It returns me nothing. I double-checked after typing `conda list`. I thought pip command automatically sort dependencies of packages under Anaconda ... so I first uninstalled using pip3 then follow your suggestions. Worked thx. But could you clarify what you mean by running the pip command under Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: Edited my answer, use conda install plotly.

Comment: ah figured that part with no prob, but I wanted to make sure. pip worked at times and not this time. So.. by 'prompt' do you mean to say under the directory of Anaconda (and not python site-packages)?

Comment: 'Prompt' was referring to windows Anaconda prompt, not relevant for OSX.
Regarding why it works sometimes? Not sure, it's possible that you have a conda environment and you used pip from there.
(conda-env)>pip install ...